How to List Files in an ISO Image Without Mounting It?
I'm working on a script to list the files in the root directory of an ISO image.
Currently, the script requires mounting the ISO to access and list the files, but I want to achieve this without mounting the ISO or relying on third-party tools.
By mounting i mean, not make them visible as disk letters, im querying multiple isos and them spam a lot of temp disks.
function Get-IsoContents {
    param (
        [string]$IsoPath
    )
    # Verify the file exists
    if (-not (Test-Path $IsoPath)) {
        Write-Error "ISO file not found: $IsoPath"
        return
    }
    try {
        # Mount the ISO image
        $mountResult = Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath $IsoPath -PassThru
        
        # Get the volume information
        $volume = $mountResult | Get-Volume
        
        # Check if volume was successfully retrieved
        if (-not $volume) {
            Write-Error "Could not retrieve volume information"
            return
        }
        
        # Get the drive letter
        $driveLetter = $volume.DriveLetter
        
        # Verify drive letter is not null or empty
        if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($driveLetter)) {
            Write-Error "No drive letter assigned to the mounted ISO"
            return
        }
        
        # Construct full path and list contents
        $fullPath = $driveLetter + ":\"
        Get-ChildItem -Path $fullPath -Force | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
    }
    catch {
        Write-Error "Error accessing ISO contents: $_"
    }
    finally {
        # Ensure the ISO is dismounted
        if ($mountResult) {
            Dismount-DiskImage -ImagePath $IsoPath | Out-Null
        }
    }
}
# Usage example
Get-IsoContents -IsoPath "C:\Users\iso.iso"


You don't want a third-party thing, but mounting is how you get the first-party thing (the filesystem driver) to see the contents of the image.

I mean mounting it as a disk letter. Im querying multiples iso

Try Superuser answer about how to use -NoDriveLetter and New-PSDrive.

@iRon expand archive works with zip files not .iso.

As suggested you can just use the -NoDriveLetter parameter to stop it from mounting the ISO as a drive. Then you can get the volume for it, use the path of that, and just list things.
This doesn't seem to work in the ISE for me, but it works fine in PowerShell v5 console.
Here's a slightly modified version of your function
function Get-IsoContents {
    param (
        [string]$IsoPath
    )
    # Verify the file exists
    if (-not (Test-Path $IsoPath)) {
        Write-Error "ISO file not found: $IsoPath"
        return
    }
    try {
        # Mount the ISO image
        $mountResult = Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath $IsoPath -PassThru -NoDriveLetter
        
        # Get the volume information
        $volume = $mountResult | Get-Volume
        
        # Check if volume was successfully retrieved
        if (-not $volume) {
            Write-Error "Could not retrieve volume information"
            return
        }
        
        Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $volume.Path -Force | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
    }
    catch {
        Write-Error "Error accessing ISO contents: $_"
    }
    finally {
        # Ensure the ISO is dismounted
        if ($mountResult) {
            Dismount-DiskImage -ImagePath $IsoPath | Out-Null
        }
    }
}
# Usage example
Get-IsoContents -IsoPath "C:\Users\iso.iso"


Technically speaking, this is still mounting it, just not providing a drive letter.

Technically speaking, the phrase I used was "mounting the ISO as a drive" which is what this does. It does mount it, but does not assign a drive designation to it. It is not listed in get-psdrive
